# No me funcionan correctamente las notificaciones push cuando la aplicación esta cerrada

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que envío notificaciones a través de Firebase. He seguido varios tutoriales en los que la idea es que se abra una actividad cuando presione la notificación. Esta acción funciona correctamente siempre y cuando la App esta abierta, pero si se encuentra cerrada o "minimizada" y presiono la notificación esta se abre desde la actividad por defecto, que en mi caso sería el SplashScreen, la verdad no me explico porque no funciona, ¿Hay algo que me puedan recomendar?

La siguiente sería la clase que conocemos como MyFirebaseMessagingService, como se puede ver le estoy diciendo que cuando presione la notificación me lleve a NotificationActivity.class y lo hace pero solo si la aplicación esta abierta.

```
package com.asecum.com.campussicapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by asecum5 on 24/08/17.
 */

public class Firebase_NotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "NOTICIAS";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        /*String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Log.d(TAG, "Mensaje recibido de: " + from);

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }*/
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                String jsonMessage = data.getString("extra_information");
                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: \n" + "Extra information: " + jsonMessage);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            showNotification(title, message);
        }
    }
    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250})
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

La siguiente es el Manifest. ¿Será posible que este olvidando algún permiso?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asecum.com.campussicapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFICATIONACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service
            android:name=".Firebase_InstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".Firebase_NotificationService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

A continuación muestro lo que adicioné en los gradle del app

Gradle del módulo:

```
dependencies {
   ...

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

y el Gradle del proyecto

```
dependencies {
   ...
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan D. Godoy. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No uses snippets de codigo para java ya que esta funcionalidad solo vale para html/js/css. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score -1):

En realidad este es el comportamiento natural,

Si abres una notificación y la aplicación continua en memoria y no ha sido destruida por el SO, se abre en donde determina tu pendingIntent que en este caso es NotificationActivity.class.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

En el caso de abrir una notificación y la aplicación esta cerrada, la Activity que determina abrir es la definida en el PendingIntent, pero tiene que realizar la carga de la aplicación, por esta razón el punto de inicio de la aplicación es la activity que tenga definido como intent filer:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

que generalmente y en tu caso es `SplashScreen`.

---

Si deseas que vaya a la Activity en la que te encontrabas, podrías guardar un id de la activity y realizar un intent en SplashScreen finalizandola.

```
switch(ULTIMA_ACTIVITY){

case MAIN_ACTITIVY :

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();

break;

case NOTIFICATION_ACTIVITY :

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();

break;

}
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta
El problema sería que la única manera de llegar al `NotificationActivity` es presionando la notificación que haya llegado, no sabría como guardar un `id` de una actividad en la que no ha estado... ¿Cómo harán los que hacen aplicaciones mas robustas? o por ejemplo ¿Porque de los tutoriales que uno encuentra por ahi si funcionan? Lo lógico sería que soy yo quien esta haciendo algo mal pero lo he mirado una y mil veces y no entiendo cual será el problema.[Este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTQ4d3ZUS8g&t=62s) tutorial resume muy bien todos los que he visto.

Comment: Los id que me refiero tu los debes definir para asignar que Activity abrir. La notificación tiene definido un pendingIntent a NotificationActivity por esta razón siempre va ahí.